# Remove array from sharedObject

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a sharedObject that contains several arrays:

sharedUploadObject:

```
[[4453] , [4454] , [4842] , [4999]];
```

How do i remove One of the array from the sharedObject?

Lets say i remove array [4453] from the object. So i end up with :

```
[[4454] , [4842] , [4999]];
```

Comment: The same way you would remove an array from a normal object - it's hard to answer specifically because I can't see what key name your arrays are associated with within `SharedObject.data` and you haven't provided any information around how you want to target the array to be removed.

Comment: the array indexes are the keys associated with the sharedObject. So i adress them like this: `SharedObject.data[4454]` . And i would like to know how to remove that specific item from the object. Not just clear it but remove it entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all read the old value from the Shared object and Modified it in your code (as local variable) and modified new value just update the shared object. 
you will find out the new value in the shared object.

Please provide me the your property name and shared object or give me your code snapshot. I will give you code for the same...

Please refer given below link

[Click Here for Details](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3sharedobject/)

Take data in  your application and clar shredobject and one again put your new data to shared object....